# How to add dynamic content to css in Next.JS

Tags: css, next.js

I am learning Next.JS and while I understand how to use getStaticProps to fetch dynamic content from a headless CMS and make it available in my JSX templates I don't see how I am supposed to access/use it in my CSS. In other SSG generators I have used you can use the templating engine to interpolate dynamic content with your css e.g.

```css
body {
    background: url('{{urlFromMyHeadlesCMS}}')
}
```

I can think of a couple of ways I might try and accomplish this but they feel somewhat janky e.g. setting the styles I want via javascript or using styled components string interpolation. Is there a cleaner, more canonical way to accomplish this in Next.JS? Is it finally time I got round to learning SASS!?

Answer (score 1):

I feel something like [*styled-jsx*](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx#external-styles) along with a `css.global` predicate would fit your need

```
/* styles.js */
import css from 'styled-jsx/css'

// Global styles
export const body = css.global`body {  background: url('{{urlFromMyHeadlesCMS}}') }`
```

*Caveats*

> I can think of a couple of ways I might try and accomplish this but they feel somewhat janky e.g. setting the styles I want via javascript or using styled components string interpolation.

> Is there a cleaner, more canonical way to accomplish this in Next.JS

I am not sure if the statements above excluded my solution but they can additionally be addressed.